# Powershell Console Menu Options - Need to add line breaks?

Tags: powershell, menu, console, switch-statement

I've created a console menu from some code I modified.

I use the following code and use the `switch` command to go to the menu choices outlined in this code:

```
# new menu for remote tasks ps1
$Title = "Remote Tasks"
$Message = "Please enter your selection below:"
$remoteRestartComputer = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&1 Restart one or more remote computer(s)", `
    "Restart one or more remote computer(s)"    
$remoteShutdownComputer = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&2 Shutdown one or more remote computer(s)", `
    "Shutdown one or more remote computer(s)" 
$wakeOnLanComputer = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&3 Start/Wake VM Station", `
    "Start/Wake VM Station"     
$getOutThisB = new-object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&4 Exit", `
    "Exit" 
$Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($remoteRestartComputer, $remoteShutdownComputer, $wakeOnLanComputer, $getOutThisB)
$selectRemoteTask = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($Title, $Message, $Options, 0)
```

The problem is in the console window it shows a couple of the choices on the same line, i.e.:

```
Remote Tasks
Please enter your selection below:
[1] 1 Restart one or more remote computer(s)
[2] 2 Shutdown one or more remote computer(s)[3] 3 Start/Wake VM Station
[4] 4 Exit[?] Help (default is "1"):
```

Any way to add line breaks so this looks nicer?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this a while ago as an answer for some question on here, I don't even remember what it was. I think it had to do with ASCII pipe characters to make borders. This will make your menu, with an optional title, and display it. Then you just need to display your Get-Host, put it in a loop, and then move on to your switch.

```
Function MenuMaker{
    param(
        [string]$Title = $null,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline = $true)][String[]]$Selections
        )

    $Width = if($Title){$Length = $Title.Length;$Length2 = $Selections|%{$_.length}|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1;$Length2,$Length|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1}else{$Selections|%{$_.length}|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1}
    $Buffer = if(($Width*1.5) -gt 78){(78-$width)/2}else{$width/4}
    if($Buffer -gt 4){$Buffer = 4}
    $MaxWidth = $Buffer*2+$Width+$($Selections.count).length
    $Menu = @()
    $Menu += "╔"+"═"*$maxwidth+"╗"
    if($Title){
        $Menu += "║"+" "*[Math]::Floor(($maxwidth-$title.Length)/2)+$Title+" "*[Math]::Ceiling(($maxwidth-$title.Length)/2)+"║"
        $Menu += "╟"+"─"*$maxwidth+"╢"
    }
    For($i=1;$i -le $Selections.count;$i++){
        $Item = "$i`. "
        $Menu += "║"+" "*$Buffer+$Item+$Selections[$i-1]+" "*($MaxWidth-$Buffer-$Item.Length-$Selections[$i-1].Length)+"║"
    }
    $Menu += "╚"+"═"*$maxwidth+"╝"
    $menu
}
```

You would call it as such:

```
MenuMaker -Title $Title -Selections "Restart one or more remote computer(s)","Shutdown one or more remote computer(s)","Start/Wake VM Station","Exit"
```

Sure, it doesn't include Help, but it does make a nice pretty menu for you. You could probably modify the function to add a -Help switch to display a `? - Help` line, or just include Help as one of your selections. Then you just do something like:

```
Do{
MenuMaker -Title $Title -Selections "Restart one or more remote computer(s)","Shutdown one or more remote computer(s)","Start/Wake VM Station","Exit"
$Selection = Read-Host "Please enter your selection (? for Help)"}While($Selection -notin (1..4) -or $Selection -eq "?")
```

**Edit:** Switch example (updated above code to include ? for help!):

```
Switch($Selection){
    4 {Continue}
    3 {Run code to Start/Wake VM Station}
    2 {Run code to shutdown remote computer}
    1 {Run code to restart remote computer}
    "?" {Run code to display Help}
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks this helps a LOT.  Menu looks much nicer.  I'm pretty new to powershell--what type of loop would I use, and would it go around the function?  Also, after calling it with MenuMaker, how would the proceeding switch command be used?  If it helps I can add the rest of my code including the switches.  Thanks again!!

Comment: The function goes at the top of the script, so it is available to call later as needed. As for the loop, I actually included an example for the loop. The `Do{` three lines there will pop up the menu and just repeat it if they don't make a valid choice. Then you can use a Switch, just like you had suggested. Give me a minute and I'll pop up an example for the Switch.

Comment: Thanks again, sir.  I very much appreciate your assistance.  I'd vote your answer up but not enough rep points yet.

Comment: No worries, I'm happy to help. If you have further questions directly regarding my answer maybe we can visit a chat room to avoid comment spam.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post, but I found your menu layout and its really well done.
I updated it so it was able to run by referencing the unicode characters since it was throwing some errors regarding special characters for me.

incase you or anyone else wanted to still use it, here it is so no one else has to go through the hassle of looking up the characters :D

```
Function New-Menu{
param(
    [string]$Title = $null,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
    ValueFromPipeline = $true)][String[]]$Selections
    )

$Width = if($Title){$Length = $Title.Length;$Length2 = $Selections|ForEach-Object{$_.length}|Sort-Object -Descending|
Select-Object -First 1;$Length2,$Length|Sort-Object -Descending|Select-Object -First 1}else{$Selections|ForEach-Object{$_.length}|
Sort-Object -Descending|Select-Object -First 1}
$Buffer = if(($Width*1.5) -gt 78){(78-$width)/2}else{$width/4}
if($Buffer -gt 4){$Buffer = 4}
$MaxWidth = $Buffer*2+$Width+$($Selections.count).length
$Menu = @()
$Menu += "$([char]0x2554)"+"$([Char]0x2550)"*$maxwidth+"$([char]0x2557)"
if($Title){
    $Menu += "$([Char]0x2551)"+" "*[Math]::Floor(($maxwidth-$title.Length)/2)+$Title+" "*[Math]::Ceiling(($maxwidth-$title.Length)/2)+"$([Char]0x2551)"
    $Menu += "$([Char]0x255F)" +"$([char]0x2500)"*$maxwidth+"$([Char]0x2562)"
}
For($i=1;$i -le $Selections.count;$i++){
    $Item = "$i`. "
    $Menu += "$([Char]0x2551)"+" "*$Buffer+$Item+$Selections[$i-1]+" "*($MaxWidth-$Buffer-$Item.Length-$Selections[$i-1].Length)+"$([Char]0x2551)"
}
$Menu += "$([char]0x255a)"+"$([Char]0x2550)"*$maxwidth+"$([char]0x255D)"
$menu
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It's partially possible with escaped backspaces (`b)

```
$OfficeOptions = @($i=0;@("No office","Office 2010","Office 2013","Office 2016") | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription ("&$i`b`b$($_)" + [Environment]::NewLine + "`b`b`b`b")
    $i++
})

$OfficeVersion = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice("Office version", "Choose office version", $OfficeOptions, 0)
```

It will however display 2 spaces on each following line.

Answer (score 0):

The following newline character worked for me

```
[Environment]::NewLine
```

Edit:
"`n" usually works (note the backtick)

Comment: Example:

    $message = "Line 1." + [Environment]::NewLine + "Line 2."

Comment: I can't make it work. @tareq could you double check to see if it works?

Comment: My understanding is that he wants new lines for the choices, not the question.  In which case this does not work.

Comment: PromptForChoice automatically trim spaces at the beginning and end of a string

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, `PromptForChoice` automatically trims spaces at the beginning and end of each option, so in order to explicitly add linebreaks (and not let them be removed), the trick is to **append a linebreak and then (after the linebreak) any other non-whitespace character** (backspace works)

`PromptForChoice` will also automatically add some spaces before each option, so in order to have all options aligned to the left the trick is to **add some backspaces (clean the whole line) and manually rewrite the option-numbers**.

**Full example** (works both in console or in Powershell ISE):

```
# default value 
$regionIndex = 0;

$regions = @("eastus", "eastus2", "westus", "westus2", "europe");
if ($host.name -eq 'ConsoleHost') { $needsLineBreak = "`n`b" } else { $needsLineBreak = "" }; # linebreak only works for console, not for ISE
$options = $regions | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription (
       "`b`b`b`b`b`b[&$($regions.IndexOf($_))] - $_"  + $needsLineBreak)
};

$regionIndex = $host.ui.PromptForChoice("Regions", 
    "Choose the Region" +
    " (default=" + ($regionIndex) + " - " + $regions[$regionIndex] +")", 
    $options, $regionIndex);

# Check if ISE Dialog was aborted (ESC)
if ($host.name -ne 'ConsoleHost' -and $regionIndex -eq $null) { return; } 

Write-Host $regions[$regionIndex];
```

**This is the Output:**

```
Regions
Choose the Region (default=0 - eastus)
[0] - eastus
[1] - eastus2
[2] - westus
[3] - westus2

[4] - europe
[?] Help (default is "0"):
```

(The extra linebreak between [3] and [4] is because `PromptForChoice` automatically calculates where linebreaks between options should be added - I don't think there's a workaround to avoid that)